# Use debug dcus option in Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

On setting "Use debug .dcus" option to True in project options, method calls in my application  does not work as expected.

Say for example,

I call a method func(a, b, c);

In the "func" definition c's value is assigned to "a" and a's values is assigned to "c" and everything goes crazy.

I tried to create it in sample application, but with no luck.  It is happening only in my live project.

Any one faced the same issue?

From delphi docs I see that Debug dcus option builds information using stack frames.  Anything related to this?

Pavan.

Comment: -1 for "everything goes crazy". :-)

Comment: Stack frames is a seperate option, Debug dcu's builds with the debug info for the VCL source code

Comment: @TOndrej : Hello Mr....Then wat else do you expect after spending hours together to find such an incredible feature?

Comment: Is this only happening when you're calling into RTL/VCL units, or also while calling methods in your own code?

Comment: It is happening in my own code.  To be very specific, I go deep inherited and at 4th level this behavior is seen for all methods.

Comment: Hmm... not build-related, not new-feature-related.  And this is only happening when you repeatedly call **inherited**?  Very strange.  Have you tried calling inherited(obj, a, d); as opposed to just "inherited;"?  I make it a point to never use naked inherited calls; they tend to cause trouble for you at unexpected points.  And if that doesn't help, I have no idea.  Try calling CodeGear.

Comment: Without code that demonstrates the problem, then we really can't do much to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't create a sample application, then it obviously must be something in your live project that is not what you might expect.

I can only suggest you tackle the problem by making a copy of your live project, and then systematically remove one thing at a time. The step that makes the problem go away will help you narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an obvious one, but did you make sure to do a full rebuild and not just a normal compile?  Anytime you change project settings, you have to do a full rebuild or you'll end up with undefined behavior.  (That's the technical term for "everything goes crazy.")

Comment: Hi Mason, yes, I rebuilt the whole project group.   I deleted all the dcu files and made sure that everything is latest built.  But the same behaviour.

Comment: And beside that, IIRC when modifying includefiles too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything with generics or anonymous methods?  Even with Update 3 installed, the Delphi 2009 compiler still has several subtle bugs in it--mostly related to the new features--that can be very difficult to reduce down to a simple test case.

Comment: Hi Mason, thank you for showing interesting in finding a solution to this problem.  Actually, I am not using any new features.  I have overloaded method with params  func1(obj : TObject; a : integer; d : Tdatetime) and func1(obj: TObject; f: Double; d: Tdatetime). First time I observed the erroneous behaviour in this case.  So I thought that it could be related with method overloading, and I gave a try by defining two seperate functions but still the same behaviour. And note that, this happens  only when I set "Use debug DCUs" option to True.If I dont set that option everything works normally.